# Android Studio - the 'xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"' generates the URI is not registered error

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, I am attempting to shrink my code by following the instructions on [Shrink Your Code and Resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)

and customize which resources to keep, creating a res/raw/keep.xml file with the following content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@layout/l_used*_c,@layout/l_used_a,@layout/l_used_b*"
    tools:discard="@layout/unused2" />
```

however the 'http://schemas.android.com/tools' line generates the "URI is not registered" error which I do not get why.

I have tried to clean project, rebuilt project, invalid caches and restart.

If I change the `<resources ..... />` to `<resources>...</resources>` then I no longer have the error message however I do not know why?